# What type does the sscanf Modifier %Fd scan?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, scanf

I have come across some legacy code that has the following type of line:

sscanf(szBuff,"%Fd %Ff %Fd %Ff"

Has anyone seeen a modifier like Fd or Ff?  If so, what does it mean?

I cant seem to find any information on it. The code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Why did you cut the example at the place where it gets interesting, i.e. the other sscanf args and their declarations?

Comment: What compiler and/or dev environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ouah pointed out, these are the same as their lower case counterparts. Why is that? For symmetry with the printf conversion specifiers. Here `%x` and `%X` write lowercase or uppercase numbers like `deadbeef` and `DEADBEEF`. The symmetry allows to use the same format string for both input with `scanf` and output with `printf`.

```
#define FMT "%F\n"

sscanf (str, FMT, &value);
printf (FMT, value);
```

Comment: Here is one line of sample code:  sscanf(szTemp, "%Ff %Ff %Ff %Ff %d %d %Fd %Fd %Ff %d %d %Fs %d", &sp_fpt0.x, &sp_fpt0.y, &sp_fpt1.x, &sp_fpt1.y,
             &iMember1, &iMember2, &sp_iMember1End, &sp_iMember2End, &sp_fDist, &iSpliceMember, &iPlumbMember,
             sp_szOrigLabel, &sp_iPlumbIntLoc);

Comment: An these are all pointers to `float` (for %F...) and `int` (for %d), right?

Comment: That is correct. The %Fs is for a char string (char sp_szOrigLabel[20])

Comment: Whoa! No, that's not correct then. A `char[]` is **not** a `float`. It looks like your system (Windows?) is not using the POSIX semantics for %F and treats the `F` as a modifier for %s! What's your system vendor and compiler/library vendor?

Comment: Understand my frustration? The char[] is not a float and neither are the integers that are being subjected to a %Fd ! I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 10. This code has been around for a LONG time.

Comment: Okay, then I'm afraid it is undocumented. The Visual Studio 10 scanf modifiers are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx "F" does not appear anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

C says for `fscanf` functions:

> (C99<sup>1</sup>, 7.19.6.2p14) The conversion specifiers A, E, F, G, and X are also valid and behave the same as, respectively, a, e, f, g, and x.

So in `%Fd`, the conversion specification is `%F` which is equivalent to `%f`. Note that the `d` is not part of the conversion specification.

For example (for `fprintf` functions `%F` is also the same as `%f`):

```
printf("%fd\n", 3.141592);
```

will print:

```
3.141592d
```

---

<sub>1. C89/C90 does not recognize the `F` conversion specifier. For example, for `fscanf` the corresponding C90 paragraph in 7.9.6.2 says: *The conversion specifiers E, G, and X are also valid and behave the same as, respectively e, g, and x*</sub>

Comment: It appears Jack is using a non-standard system, where "%Fs" actually needs a pointer-to-char to go with it, and "F" is a modifier.

Answer (score 1):

`%F` is a POSIX (and C99) extension.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html

> "The conversion specifiers A, E, F, G, and X are also valid and shall be equivalent to a, e, f, g, and x, respectively."